# How to enable/disable occurrence highlighting in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Syntax occurrence highlighting is no longer working in my Eclipse workspace and I can't find a way to enable it again. It is working when I change the workspace. I tried to clear the cache data but it is not working. Is there a way to enable and disable occurrence highlighting?

Comment: You may be opening a file with the wrong editor. Right click on the file and choose 'Open With' to choose an editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> disables and enables this feature, which is called Mark Occurrences.

Comment: There is also a toolbar button to toggle it on and off. The icon looks like the tip of a yellow highlighter pen.